# What does setting "max_execution_time" to "-1" do?

Tags: php

I saw this in a script I have to work with. What does setting "max_execution_time" to "-1" do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sets the maximum execution time for a script to 2**32-1 (or perhaps 2**64-1) seconds, which is a reasonable approximation of "forever". Note that the *actual* value to make a script run forever is **0**.

Comment: Because that's what negative numbers *really* are: [very, very high positive numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php), there is no specific designation.

My best guess would be that it would unset any limits, and allow it to run forever (*a la* setting it to `0`).

From a few other sources, it would appear, though, that it would set it to the **max** timeout, since the value *appears* to be an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not totally sure about it, but my guess is that is the max timeout, but for the setting of the server on which php it is running.

I have this value set and asked my provider to set the value to 300, the answer was that since I'm on a shared hosting the max value is set to 120 (even if it results to me -1).

Comment: I'm rather sorry to say this to you, but you always **must** be sure when you answer questions in SO. We need quality answers, and quality answers are *sure* answers.