# what is the worse effect if is set php max_execution_time to -1

Tags: php, codeigniter, unix, optimization, ini

i am working  Performance Optimizations of an report (CodeIgniter)
due to huge process load or memory usage , i am not exactly sure about, it got stopped during report generation

sum how i manage to decrees the memory usage but process time per entity is still high 
 those i am trying to decrease the time ...

at the same time what if i set the *max_execution_time* to -1

some thing like this

```
 $max_execution_time  = ini_get("max_execution_time");
 ini_set("max_execution_time", -1);
```

massive code block

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", $max_execution_time);
```

if i do this what worse effect i can get ...in any circumstances

I am not worrying about if the code got executed and finises it job 
but with the effect while user terminates browser is their would be any effect's if their is any....

Comment: Well, you could write code so broken that it never terminates (or doesn't terminate within any reasonable amount of time) and prevent subsequent requests from being handled. The sounds pretty bad. The max execution time is designed such that such code will be forcible aborted. (Although, hopefully the web-server also has its own timeouts/monitoring.)

Comment: Check this link it for your question [execution limit][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371406/what-does-setting-max-execution-time-to-1-do